# Should I resize my loaded images when switching to full screen in Flash

Tags: flash, resize, jpeg, fullscreen

I have a swf that loads images from my server and resizes them to fit the 800x600 stage size. The original images are stored at 1024x768 max pixels. The user can press a button to go into fullscreen mode. What should I do to show the images at the best quality?

a) should I resize the loaded images to their max size (1024x768)
b) do I need to reload the entire image if it has been resized to 800x600 or is the original image still accessible and I can replace the 800x600 image with the original?

I am using AS2 and Flash 8 (but require users to have Flash Player 10 for fullscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the images are resized on the client (e.g. you loaded full-sized images from the server). In that case, there's no need to reload the images. You have the full sized images in memory on the client. Just set a new size for the images, and the quality is as good as it's going to get.

If you have resized the images on the server you will of course have to reload the images.

Comment: Yes I resize on the client so I will resize to fit fullscreen rather than leave them at 800x600 blown up. thanks